# What is the ordering in tab2list for bag ETS?

Tags: erlang, ets

I was playing with `bag` table a bit:

```
30> W = ets:new(w, [bag]).
#Ref<0.616284823.3413770252.143386>
31> ets:insert(W, [{1, a}, {2, a}, {1, b}, {2, b}, {a}, {b}]).
true
32> ets:tab2list(W).
[{1,a},{1,b},{b},{a},{2,a},{2,b}]
```

I totally don't understand how does the ordering work here. Why are the smallest tuples in the middle? How are they greater than `{1,_}` but smaller than `{2,_}`?

---

EDIT: the results in the example come from OTP21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs for [ets:lookup/2](http://www2.erlang.se/documentation/doc-4.8.2/lib/stdlib-1.6.1/doc/html/ets.html):

> The time order of object insertions is preserved.

That means that when two tuples with the same key are inserted, their ordering is determined by the time of insertion.  I don't know if that also holds true for `ets:tab2list/1`.  In any case, that is the ONLY guarantee.  And, your results seem to behave consistently with that ONE guarantee.

I looked at the source code for `ets:tab2list/1`, and it calls `ets:first/1`--not `ets:lookup/2`.  The docs for [ets:first/1](https://erldocs.com/21.0/stdlib/ets.html?i=1&search=ets:firs#first/1) say:

> For an ordered_set table, the first key in Erlang term order is
> returned. For other table types, the first key according to the
> internal order of the table is returned.

Because the order of the returned keys from an `ordered_set` is mentioned, but the order of the returned keys from a `bag` is said to be "according to the internal order of the table", I don't think you can count on `ets:first/1` to return the keys in ANY order.  Therefore, you must treat the list returned by `tab2list/1` as unordered.

And, straight from rvirding himself:

> With a set, bag or duplicate_bag the order in which you get the keys
> is internal. This irrespective of whether you use `match`, `select` or
> `first` and `next`. I was referring to the ordering of elements of one
> key in a bag or duplicate_bag returned when doing a `lookup`, `match`
> or `select` [where the time order of object insertions is preserved; the first object inserted with the specified key is the first in the resulting list, and so on.]
>
> [Otherwise,] the internal ordering of keys is not defined and you can never depend
> on it because as you say it can change between releases. Except of
> course for type ordered_set where the ordering is defined.
>
> https://elixirforum.com/t/retrieval-in-ets/10413/2

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect any order in the returned list, especially when you define the table as a "bag". There is no assumption about the order of the returned list in the documentation.

By the way, I copy/paste your commands in my erlang shell, and I got a different result: `[{1,b},{1,a},{b},{a},{2,b},{2,a}]`. No conclusion, maybe you didn't copy/paste all the commands and results but edit/modify some of them, maybe the result depends on the ets library version, maybe it depends on the "realtime" conditions.

Comment: Indeed, tried on newer version of erl and got the same results as you. The example from the question comes from OTP21, which I didn't expect to make any difference

Comment: So there is a good chance that it depends on the library version. There are many operations that are not described: do they store the records in serial or parallel, what is the internal representation of ETS, How do they build the list (using first and next?)...